# I'm trying to add guitar tabs to a music video, do you know any software to do it?

Tags: video-editor, music

The question is how can I add guitar tabs to my video? Software?
I am recording a guitar performance and would like to add the guitar tabs for the students to follow.  I watched a Japanese video with a bottom part showing  a movie of how the fingers are placed. Please see below link.

Comment: Good question. I think it is more about video editing software than about music. Is there a stackexchange for that?

Comment: You are right Max, could be more about video editing software combined with tab editing software... kind of tricky,

Comment: Use you favorite graphics tool to create the tabs as JPEG files, then Premier Pro or Vegas pro (or your preferred editor) to edit the images together

Answer (score 1):

Try to break your task into elementary blocks. If you can't solve the problem, break it into even smaller blocks.

Tabs? If which format? Maybe in form of MIDI files? Or even text on papers? Or in some form of txt files? It is a very important question. In some cases you must convert your tabs from one format to another.

What do you want add to the video? You can add only sequences of images or sounds, not "guitar tabs". You need draw some images first. For example, images with the fretboard and white circles on it.

If I had such a task, I would first convert the tabs into a form convenient for me. Then I would write a simple program that would draw pictures. This can be a C program, a Python script, or a script for 3ds max. Then I can use ffmpeg to assemble such images. And, as final task, I will use some software like Premiere or Final Cut to compose and sync my images with video.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an image editor to draw a picture of the tab. If you use a tool that allows layers, such as Photoshop, you can create a base layer with the image of the neck of the guitar, and then put the actual fret dots on higher layers. You can group the dots into folders for specific chords in specific positions. (For example, you might have a folder that contains all the dots for a-minor in one position, and another for all the dots for C-major in a different position.) Then you can easily turn on just the folder you need and export the image for use in your video.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Guitar player pro has a fretboard emulator along with a tab generator. So create your tab in GPP, generate the fretboard finger placements, export to video editing sofware and then its a case of synchronisation between the two.